# How do we prove commutativity of a diagram?

Tags: graph-theory, category-theory

How do we prove commutativity of a diagram?

There may be an infinite number of paths. We can't enumerate all paths.

Comment: You prove that every "cell" is commutative.

Comment: @DanielFischer What is "cell"? Why is this enough?

Comment: An empty space enclosed by arrows (and objects at the corners). Usually a triangle or quadrangle. Of course that method works only for sufficiently regular diagrams, but I haven't seen infinite irregular diagrams arise so far. It works because you can transform any two paths between to fixed objects in a sufficiently regular diagram into each other by a finite sequence of "jumps over a single cell".

Comment: Do you have a situation at hand where a diagram occurs that is sufficiently "exotic" to really make deep thoughts about this? In more complicated situation it is common to explictly specify which "cells" commute (and in standard situations "the diagram commutes" is taken to mean "all obvious cells commute")

Comment: @DanielFischer That description seems to apply (nicely) to planar graphs only

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen True. For non-planar diagrams, we should include cuboids, tetrahedra, and the like as usual cells, but my imagination doesn't go far in that area.

Comment: Isn't referring to a particular diagram as planar "proof by a picture"? How to show that a diagram is planar without writing actual X-Y equations of the curves which serve as graph edges?

Comment: Compare your argument with: "how do your prove that $n < n + 99$ for every natural number $n$? You can't enumerate all natural numbers." Mathematicians have evolved one or two techniques like mathematical induction for dealing with the infinite.

Comment: @RobArthan I haven't asked whether "a technique for dealing with the infinite" exists. I ask about a particular technique tailored with category theory diagrams, which I can use to prove particular results for a specific diagram

Comment: But you included an objection in your question: you wrote "there may be an infinite number of paths. We can't enumerate all paths."" My comment was about that objection.