# Help to write a proof (category theory diagram)

Tags: graph-theory, category-theory, proof-writing, diagram-chasing

It is known that $f$, $g$, $h$ are isomorphisms.

It is known that $g\circ f = h^{-1}$.

I need to write down the proof of the following theorem. I am an amateur mathematician and am not an expert in category theory but write a book. The book shall contain this proof. Please help with wording the proof and base results and/or references to other books/articles I can use. (I am going to acknowledge you in my book.)

**Theorem** The diagram is commutative, every cycle in the diagram is an identity.

[image]

Related question:
[How do we prove commutativity of a diagram?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1385636/how-do-we-prove-commutativity-of-a-diagram)

Comment: Use induction. For big enough cycles a smaller cycle must appear as part of your composition (by the pigeonhole principle) . Contract by that cycle, and then use the induction hypothesis.

Comment: In this case you would just need to explicitly check every cycle of length at most 3 is the identity.

Comment: @PVAL But how to show that every cycle is composed from cycles of the length no more than 3?

Comment: @PVAL Also this proves only that cycles are identities, but we need to prove also that the diagram is commutative

Comment: Any composition of 3 length, hits one point twice (by the pigeonhole principle). So either this path  is a cycle or it is a cycle composed with another composition.

Comment: To show the diagram is commutative just use that $\tau=\sigma$ for any composition ending at the same endpoint if and only if $\tau\circ(\sigma)^{-1}$ is the identity.

Comment: What about the similar question for a square graph?

Comment: There are three non-trivial cycles of length three: $hgf, gfh, fhg$. For two of them, being the identity follows directly from $h^{-1}=gf$, and for the third one, we have $fhg = fhgff^{-1} = fhh^{-1}f^{-1} = 1_C$

Comment: @porton I answered your question.  Feel free to discuss it in the comments.  Where's your book?  I would like to view it.

Comment: @ShineOnYouCrazyDiamond I proved it myself years ago (with simple induction). The proof is available in my book Algebraic General Topology that reinvents general topology in a more general (and algebraic) way: http://www.mathematics21.org/algebraic-general-topology.html (the biggest discoveries in general topology since 1937, for example, limits are generalized for discontinuous functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can argue reasonably as the commenters did, but that avoids a perfectly good example on which to hone your more general category theory skills.

You're given that $f, g, h$ are isomorphisms, and that $g\circ f = h^{-1}$.  If you're like me, you desire a somewhat more diagrammatic proof.  Here is one I came up with that also demonstrates the drawing capabilities of an app I'm creating called BananaCats.

Note that $g \circ f = h^{-1}$ has an associated commuting triangle.  And recall the definition of identity morphism on $X$, that it takes any function into or out of $X$ to itself when composed, respectively.

So, the idea is to show that the only function $l$ can be is $\text{id}_X$ based solely on that definition, because that $\text{id}_X$ is the unique such function is a basic property of categories.

[image: Two commuting triangles]

Above, the two triangles commute by definition, and our proof goal is to show that the square commutes.  Below, check that this diagram also commutes,

[image: Commuting polygons and chords.]

Alternatively, invoke the **polygon chord lemma**.

> **Lemma.** Given a commuting polygon and a chord drawn that is the composition of some of its sides, then the two subpolygons also commute!

So in that image, clearly we can draw it backwards: first the outer polygon, and then take the composition of the two sides $g\circ f$ which equal $h^{-1}$ by definition.

That lemma probably doesn't exist in literature, but it's the perfect tool for reasoning visually about these category diagrams.

One final application of the lemma to a subpolygon of the previous diagram give:

[image: Commuting subpolygon and a chord.]

Now, we have that $k = k \circ (fgh)$.

You must repeat the process for an arrow *entering $C$*.  Once you do that, you know that $fgh = \text{id}_C$ is indeed true.  Now argue by symmetry that the rest of the cycles also compose to $\text{id}_X$ on their respective objects.  $\blacksquare$

I like this proof way more than the commenters' proofs, because I got to practice actual category theory in proving the statement.